# Dynamically show full-sized images on thumbnail mouseover in PHP

Tags: javascript, image

I want to show an image when I mouse over a thumbnail, like [this website](http://www.someecards.com/apology-collection-cards/most-sent-today) does. How can I do this, in PHP?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use frontend as jquery/javascript -> onmouseover -> ajax to server to fetch full size image -> successful return -> show image in modal box or something..

or instead of re-inventing the wheel, you could look at the following too : 
http://www.ajaxrain.com/tag?tag=Tooltips
http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: No need for AJAX. Popping up a standard image tag with a bigger-sized version of the image is perfectly sufficient.